# Toggling classes with Vue Js, grabbing all props from the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is what I have in index.php, a `side-nav` component

```
<div class="container">
    <side-nav></side-nav>
</div>
```

This is what I have in SideNav.vue

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <nav-section name="General">
        <nav-item name="Home">
            <nav-child name="Dahsboard 1" url="#"></nav-child>
            <nav-child name="Dahsboard 2" url="#"></nav-child>
        </nav-item>

        <nav-item name="Settings">
            <nav-child name="Setting 1" url="#"></nav-child>
            <nav-child name="Setting 2" url="#"></nav-child>
        </nav-item>

        <nav-item name="Admin">
            <nav-child name="Admin 1" url="#"></nav-child>
            <nav-child name="Admin 2" url="#"></nav-child>
        </nav-item>
    </nav-section>

    <nav-section name="Data Analysis">
        <nav-item name="Data Source">
            <nav-child name="Source 1" url="#"></nav-child>
            <nav-child name="Source 2" url="#"></nav-child>
        </nav-item>

        <nav-item name="Visualization">
            <nav-child name="Chart 1" url="#"></nav-child>
            <nav-child name="Chart 2" url="#"></nav-child>
        </nav-item>

        <nav-item name="Others">
            <nav-child name="Other 1" url="#"></nav-child>
            <nav-child name="Other 2" url="#"></nav-child>
        </nav-item>
    </nav-section>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import NavSection from './NavSection.vue'
    import NavItem from './NavItem.vue'
    import NavChild from './NavChild.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            'nav-section':NavSection,
            'nav-item':   NavItem,
            'nav-child':  NavChild,
        },

        data() {
            return {

            }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },


    }
</script>
```

This is what I have in NavSection.vue

```
<template>
    <section>
        <h6>{{ name }}</h6>

        <ul>
            <slot></slot>
        </ul>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name'],

        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

This is what I have in NavItem.vue

```
<template>
    <li>
        <a @click="toggleClass">{{ name }}</a>

        <ul :class="{ 'active': isActive}">
            <slot></slot>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name'],

        data() {
            return {
                isActive: false,
                names: []
            }
        },

        created() {
            //this returns all the names in console
            console.log(this.name)

            //However, saving it to data->names array, only saves the clicked item
            this.names = this.name
        },

        methods: {

            toggleClass() {
                this.isActive = true

                //this works, but I want the value to go back to FALSE once I clicked on another item

                //one way I think it can be accomplished is comparing the cliked item's name prop with all the names
                //something like this, (refer to created method)
                this.names.forEach(element => {
                    this.isActive = (element.name == this.names)
                })

            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

And this is what I have in NavChild.vue

```
<template>
    <li>
        <a :href="url">{{ name }}</a>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'url'],

        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, each `navSection` has several `navItem` and each `navItem` has several `navChild` components. When the function `toggleClass` triggered by clicking on each anchor tag in the `NavItem`, I want 1. the `isActive` property should update its value to `TRUE` for that particular item and 2. `isActive` goes back to `False` once I click on another item inside the each section.

I had one idea that could work, as commented in the `NavItem.vue` file, but unfortunately I could't find a way to grab all the `props`, say `name` prop, for each item from the `NavItem` component. Is there any way to grab and save all the passed data for a particular `prop`?

Any suggestion for improving the code, or any other convenient way to accomplish the same stuff would be greatly appreciated. Happy coding!

Comment: You're using slots, which are not the same as child components. The radio-group behavior requires coordination between the NavItems and their NavSection, which will be awkward if they are not set up as parent/child.

Comment: any simple jsfiddle example to accomplish the same thing without using slot? I used slots because it makes it very readable and clean when it comes to add new item in the nav section. But I'd be okay with any other neat approach @RoyJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're kind of HTML-oriented in your approach, here, and the Vue approach is to be model-oriented. So instead of laying out your model structure in the HTML, you should make a data model with the hierarchy you want, and have your components render it.

I made my app the section level, since you're concerned with what happens below that level. I created a data model like the first section of your example.

The trick to select-only-one behavior is that there should be one variable to hold the currently selected value. That value is owned by the parent. Each child gets a prop telling it whether it is the selected value.

When a child becomes selected, it emits an event, which the parent processes (this is [the Vue way of child-to-parent communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)).

```js
Vue.component('nav-child', {
  template: '#nav-child-template',
  props: ['name', 'url']
});

Vue.component('nav-item', {
  template: '#nav-item-template',
  props: ['name', 'children', 'isActive'],
  methods: {
    toggleClass() {
      this.$emit('activate', this.isActive ? null : this.name);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#nav-section',
  data: {
    activeItem: null,
    items: [{
        name: 'Home',
        children: [{
            name: 'Dashboard 1',
            url: '#'
          },
          {
            name: 'Dashboard 2',
            url: '#'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Settings',
        children: [{
            name: 'Setting 1',
            url: '#'
          },
          {
            name: 'Setting 2',
            url: '#'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    activate(name) {
      this.activeItem = name;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="nav-child-template">
    <li>
        <a :href="url">{{ name }}</a>
    </li>
</template>

<template id="nav-item-template">
    <li>
        <a @click="toggleClass">{{ name }}</a>

        <ul :class="{ 'active': isActive}">
            <li is="nav-child" v-for="child in children" :name="child.name" :url="child.url"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>

<ul id="nav-section">
  <li is="nav-item" v-for="item in items" :name="item.name" :is-active="activeItem === item.name" :children="item.children" @activate="activate"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I kind of started with a similar approach where instead of emitting an event, I simply compared the array of items' names with the selected one. The only issue is that it achieves the "switching items" effect, but disables the toggling effect. The reason why I need that is I had an admin menu I developed quite a long time ago and I used jQuery for that which was literally 10 seconds job. Can you think of an way I can achieve the same thing without compromising the "self toggling" feature? Don't mind if I sound dumb. Newbie in Vue.

Comment: Sure, I updated the code. Just have it emit null instead of the current item if the current item is already active.

Comment: Your comments solved the issues and enriched my understandings. Hope someone will find this useful too :)